# How to send email using two factor authentication enabled office365 email account in asp.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, office365, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to send email using **office365** e-mail account that has enabled the **two-factor authentication**. It gives an authentication failed error. For email accounts that have not enabled the two-factor authentication works fine. How to resolve this issue?

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
   client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(appSettings["Port"]);
   client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   client.Host = "smtp.office365.com"; 
   client.EnableSsl = true;
   client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SenderMailAddress, SenderMailPassword); 
   email.Subject = String.Format("{0}", txtMailSubject.Text);
   //                   
   email.Body = String.Format("{0}", text);

   email.IsBodyHtml = true;                  

   client.Send(email);
}
```

Error message is

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: The SMTP server requires a secure
>   connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response
>   was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated at
>   System.Net.Mail.MailCommand.CheckResponse

Comment: You can probably get around this by using [App Passwords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords)

Comment: @Manusha have you solved your problem using the solution provided by Brendan Green?

Comment: @Marc No I couldn't find a solution. So I removed two factor authentication from that e mail account.

Comment: Create and use an app password at https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/AppPasswords.aspx Your exchange administrator must enable this for 2FA users. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/user-help/multi-factor-authentication-end-user-app-passwords#create-and-delete-app-passwords-using-the-office-365-portal

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an application password, then use the new application password in your code, check this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/using-app-passwords-with-apps-that-don-t-support-two-step-verification-5896ed9b-4263-e681-128a-a6f2979a7944)

Comment: Microsoft recomend not to use SmtpClient and change to https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit

Answer (score -4):

```
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress("fromid");
            MailAddress to = new MailAddress("toID");
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = "Using the new SMTP client.";
            message.Body = @"The sensor get offline ...";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
            client.Host = "hostID"; 
            client.Port = 587;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential
            {
                UserName = "**********",
                Password = "*************,
            };
            Console.WriteLine("Sending an email message to {0} using the SMTPhost {1}.");
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this will solve the 2 factor authentication ?